# Update statement is only inserting one value

Tags: sql

I have data in one table (OWNER) i'm trying to use to update the data in another table (TAX_BILL_INFO).  I've written an update statement to take the value from one column (owner.ownername) and insert that value into another column (tax_bill_info.mailername) where they have the same ID (taxbillid).  below is my statement that I used:

```
UPDATE TAX_BILL_INFO
SET       Mailername = OWNER.Ownername
FROM  TAX_BILL_INFO INNER JOIN
               OWNER ON TAX_BILL_INFO.TaxBillID = OWNER.TaxBillID
where taxyear = '2013' and (mailername = '' or mailername = ' ' or mailername is null) and (purchasername = '' or purchasername = ' ' or purchasername is null)
```

The columns are updating, it is only putting the FIRST value from OWNER into EVERY column in tax_bill_info. (ex. john smith, john smith, john smith).  Are my where criteria throwing this off?  Or could it be something else?

EDIT

If I use this select query:

```
select owner.OwnerName
FROM  owner INNER JOIN
TAX_BILL_INFO ON TAX_BILL_INFO.TaxBillID = OWNER.TaxBillID
```

the names pull as they should.  If i do a select query from the table I need the data entered into, it gives me the same dupliacte name for every row:

```
SELECT MAILERNAME
FROM  TAX_BILL_INFO INNER JOIN
OWNER ON TAX_BILL_INFO.TaxBillID
```

Comment: What does a select with the same parameters produce? What Database System do you have?

Comment: show us the schema, there must be something wrong with the select statement or the query must be returning only 1st row.

Comment: Do you mean SELECT MAILERNAME
FROM  TAX_BILL_INFO INNER JOIN
OWNER ON TAX_BILL_INFO.TaxBillID = OWNER.TaxBillID?